# Unclear math contest solution

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

I'm having difficulty understanding this solution to a problem in an old math contest. I understand everything up to the word "Hence". Can anybody explain this to me?

**Question**

[image]

**Answer**

[image]

Comment: If $a^5=-3+9a-a^2$ and $b$ and $c$ satisfy the same equality, then we add and we get ...

Comment: With which part of the solution were you having trouble?

Comment: Ohhh, mfl just made me understand it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The three roots satisfy the polynomial.  So, from 
$$ x^5 = \cdots = -3 + 9x - x^2  $$
we get \begin{align*}
a^5 &= -3 + 9a - a^2  \\
b^5 &= -3 + 9b - b^2  \\
c^5 &= -3 + 9c - c^2  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Summing these, we get 
$$ a^5 + b^5 + c^5 = 3(-3) + 9(a+b+c) - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) = \dots  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, I finally understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: From Vieta's theorem:
$$a+b+c=0, ab+bc+ac=-3, abc=-1.$$
We can find:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ac)=0^2-2(-3)=6.$$

From the equation:
$$\begin{cases} a^3=3a-1 \\ b^3=3b-1 \\ c^3=3c-1 \end{cases} \Rightarrow a^3+b^3+c^3=3(a+b+c)-3=-3.$$
Multiply the two:
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^3+b^3+c^3)=-18 \Rightarrow$$
$$a^5+b^5+c^5+(abc)^2(ab+bc+ac)=-18 \Rightarrow$$
$$a^5+b^5+c^5=-18-(-1)^2(-3)=-15.$$

Comment: That's a really cool solution!